# render react table with nested JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, datatable, nested

I have a nested JSON which I am trying to render it into a table. The idea is to populate  by iterating through the JSON. My issue is when I am Iterating through **Tags** and trying to populate  in the environment Column. It works fine if the key exists, but if the key doesn't exist it shifts TD's to previous columns.

For example, below in the image, you can see in the first row that **web** to ENV column, instead of Purpose column. for the other two, the table renders fine since the key exists.

[image: Table]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table } from "reactstrap";
class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        id: "1",
        States: "many",
        Purpose: "web",
        Tags: [
          {
            Key: "Name",
            Value: "server1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        States: "Single",
        Purpose: "App",
        Tags: [
          {
            Key: "Name",
            Value: "server2"
          },
          {
            Key: "env",
            Value: "qa"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        States: "None",
        Purpose: "DB",
        Tags: [
          {
            Key: "env",
            Value: "qa"
          },
          {
            Key: "Name",
            Value: "server3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  render() {
    let envs;
    return (
      <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
        <thead className="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">States</th>
            <th scope="col">Env</th>
            <th scope="col">Purpose</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.data.map(info => (
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{info.id}</th>
              <td>{info.States}</td>
              {info.Tags.filter(env => env.Key === "env").map(e => (
                <td>{e.Value}</td>
              ))}
              <td>{info.Purpose}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your render method, you can do:

```
<td>{info.Tags.filter(env => env.Key === "env").map(e => e.Value).join(' ')}</td>
```

So instead of wrapping the returned value from the map in `td`, you have to wrap the entire thing in the tags.

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you so much. I spent a lot of hours on this trying to figure out. finally, it works. thanks again.